# Wordpress - How and Where to add the script for my custom menu?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to PHP/Wordpress/Javascript and am trying to convert my website built using CSS and HTML into a theme using PHP for Wordpress.

I have an off-screen menu that opens and closes. Where do I put the script for this in my Wordpress files? And how do I do this correctly?

Currently, I have the HTML copied below in my header.php and the CSS copied below in my style.css

Here is my menu HTML:

```
<h1 class="menu">
 <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
  </a>
  <br>
  <a href=""> &nbsp; &nbsp; - p o r t f o l i o</a> <br>
  <a href=""> &nbsp; &nbsp; - m e e t &nbsp; m e</a><br>
  <a href=""> &nbsp; &nbsp; - i n s t a </a><br>
  <a href="#">  &nbsp; &nbsp; - p r i n t e d</a><br>
  <a href="#">  &nbsp; &nbsp; - c i a o</a>
 </div>

 <div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()"> <img src="hamburger.png"/> </div>
</h1>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
   <h1 class="menu">
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</h1>
```

Here is my CSS

```
.sidenav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 70px;
transition: 0.5s;
opacity: 0.8;
}

.sidenav a {
padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 16px;
color: #000000;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
color: #BCBCBC;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
margin-left: 10px;
font-size: 36px;
padding-top: 11px;
}


.openbtn {
background-color: #fffff;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-top: 0;
padding-top: 0;
height: 45px;
}

.openbtn a:active{
color: #ffffff;
}

.menu {
width: 5%;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to add scripts to your Wordpress website is to register them and enqueue them. Wordpress keeps a list of scripts that should execute when the page loads. By registering and enqueuing your scripts you can add them to this list, give them an execution priority, decide if they load in the header/footer and much more. Registering and enqueueing scripts should be done via the [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action hook. Once you attach a function to that hook you then use the [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and function then [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) function to register and enqueue to script respectively.

Let me give you an example. Paste the following code inside your theme's functions.php file:

```
function add_menu_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script( 'menuScript', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/menu.js', array(), null, TRUE);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'menuScript' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_menu_scripts' );
```

This code block will add the `add_menu_scripts` function to the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action hook. Inside the `add_menu_scripts` function you can see that we are giving your file a handle name (a nickname), specifying the file location, adding dependencies (in this case there are none so an empty array is giving), giving the file a version (this is optional so I am passing NULL instead) and finally specifying that the script should be loaded in the footer.

Comment: This is helpful information. Which files do each of the enqueueing scripts go into and does it matter where in that file?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the file is - you specify the file's location as the second parameter of the wp_enqueue_scripts. Also make sure you set the sixth paramter to boolean TRUE to load the script in the footer (since you are targeting DOM elements).

Comment: I added an example to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: The example helped a lot! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the `header.php` it's better not to hardcode it and let the native wordpress functionality of creating the page

Take a peek at `https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus`

Comment: hmm I see the function to register the name of my menu and the function to tell the theme where I want the menus to show up, but I don't see exactly where to plug in the js I have above. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You should put those scripts into a separate file, then use wp_enqueue_script() to call it:

```
wp_enqueue_script(
    'offset-menu',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/offset-menu.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.0',
    true
);
```

You can learn more from [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)